# Transpose a higher dimension matrix

Tags: matrices

We know how to traverse a quadratic matrix. The formation law is $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$. But what about a cubic matrix? And how can I traverse a higher dimension matrix? I do not know. Do you?

Thank you!

Comment: Traverse? Do you mean **transpose**?

Comment: Quadratic matrix? Cubic matrix? Do you mean rank one and rank two tensors? There are as many way to swap pairs of indices of a tensor as there are pairs of indices. The real question is why and for what purpose you would swap pairs of indices.

Comment: Sorry, I am with graph context in mind. I thank you for the correction. I mean a square matrix, not quadratic. In this case, the matrix has dimension greater than 2.

Comment: From a computational perspective, freeze all indices except one, flip respective rows from 1 to i-dimension and repeat it to other dimensions seems the most reasonable manner to  operate tensors transpose-wise. Do you agree?

Comment: I don't think we use the word "dimensions" for the indices. I am not sure what "flip respective rows from 1 to i-dimension" means, and it seems completely arbitrary to me (what does "most reasonable manner" mean here?).

Comment: It works for 2D tensors: First flip left-right all rows, and then all columns and you get the transpose. In the same way, flip all dimension-i rows and proceed to the next.